# set a boolean value

Tags: java, boolean

Hi I'm working with boolean values and I'm a little bit confused. I have a boolean value:

```
boolean answer;
```

This can have two values : yes or not.

If I insert from standard input the string "yes" it became true otherwise false. How can i do?

Comment: Bit confused, do you want to use boolean, and then depending on input from the user, set it to true or false? Or do you want to have a item that can be set to yes or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

assuming input is your string:

`boolean answer = input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes");`

Comment: You don't need the `? true : false`.

Comment: what mean that symbol ? and : ?

Comment: Why the ternary?  Just do 'answer = input.equalsIgnoresCase("yes")'

Comment: Ha, yeah - that is true.  Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: Mazzy, it is the Ternary operation for Java.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Vala.2C_Objective-C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript.2C_ActionScript

Answer (score 3):

Something like this may be of value:

```
private static final Set yesSet = new HashSet( Arrays.asList( new String[] {"1", "aam", "ae", "ām", "ano", "âre", "avunu", "awo", "aye", "ayo", "baht", "bai",
  "bale", "bele", "beli", "ben", "cha", "chaï", "da", "dai", "doy", "e", "é", "éé", "eh", "èh", "ehe", "eja", "eny", "ere", "euh", "evet", "éwa", "giai",
  "ha", "haan", "hai", "hoon", "iè", "igen", "iva", "já", "jā", "ja", "jah", "jes", "jo", "ken", "kha", "khrap", "kyllä", "leo", "naam", "ndiyo", "o", "òc",
  "on", "oo", "opo", "oui", "ova", "ovu", "oyi", "po", "sci", "se", "shi", "si", "sim", "taip", "tak", "tiao", "true", "v", "waaw", "wè", "wi", "ya", "yan",
  "ydw", "yea", "yebo", "yego", "yes", "yo", "yoh", "za", "За", "Так", "Тийм", "نعم", "ใช่", "ค่ะ", "ครับ",
} ) );
public static final boolean stringToBool ( String s ) {
  return ( yesSet.contains( s.toLowerCase() ) );
}
```

Derived from [FreeLang](http://www.freelang.net/expressions/yes.php)

Comment: I believe because some of those characters are not valid UTF-8, the standard for storing java files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a string comparison.  Use `String.equals`:

```
String a = "foo";
String b = "bar";
boolean c = a.equals(b);
```

Comment: this is the most elegant way to do it, perhaps using `equalsIgnoreCase` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is saved into response (string response):

```
if(response.equals("yes")){
 answer = true;
}else{
 answer = false;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the conditional, just assign straight to `answer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean answer;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = "";
try{
   input = br.readLine();
}
catch(IOException e){}

if (input.compareTo("yes") == 0)
{ 
   answer= True;
}
else{
   answer = False;
}
```

Comment: Why is everybody setting the value of a `boolean` by performing an `if` conditional on a `boolean`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm not performing the `if` on the `boolean`, I'm performing the `if` on the user input

Comment: Yes you are.  `input.compareTo("yes") == 0` is a `boolean`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am comparing `input` with the String `"yes"`, if they are equal `compareTo` will return 0.

Comment: You can just do `answer = (input.compareTo("yes") == 0);`.  Or even better, just use `equals`.

Comment: @Neeta I think Oli means you're wasting time.  You could accomplish the same thing with `answer=input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes");` and save space.  It may not always be as readable to others though.

Comment: @Sheriff Ah yes, that is true. I write code as I understand it, and which goes along with the way I think (step by step). I agree that way would save space/would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
boolean answer;
String input = "yes"
if (input.equals("yes")) {
   answer = true;
}
```

Comment: Why is everybody setting the value of a `boolean` by performing an `if` conditional on a `boolean`?

Comment: Good point, although sometimes readability is important, too.  And it's also possible you'd want to do other things if the input was "yes", as well, meaning an 'if' block would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean answer = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
```